# In c# where in clause works for integers?

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

Here i am using where clause for integers. Is it possible ? As i am not getting the required result.

```
 ProjectDetail objProjlst1 = _ProjectContext.ProjectDetails.Where(x => x.Phase == Phase).SingleOrDefault();

    if(objProjlst1!= null){
    return true;
    }

    else
    {
    return false;
    }
```

Here Phase is an integer.
I am getting an error "Object object" when i run the whole web application

Comment: Yes it is possible to use integers. All you have to do is make sure that your expression inside returns boolean value.

Comment: Well, what *do* you get? There isn't enough information here to help you.

Comment: Two possibilities, either your `ProjectDetails` doesn't contain a matching integer for `Phase`, or it contains more than one that matches.

Comment: I think you want to use `.Any()` and just return that

Comment: I wanted to know if it will work for integers as i read somewhere that it works only for strings. There must be some other issue with my code.Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You possibly want `FirstOrDefault()` depending on whether you were expecting multiple matches. Alternatively this could be written as `return _ProjectContext.ProjectDetails.Any(x => x.Phase == Phase);`. This will return true for one or more matches, false for 0. I suppose both depend on whether you expect multiple matches not.

Comment: What would make you believe it WOULDN'T work for integers?  Doubting the compiler before doubting your code is a rough and rugged road.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If `_ProjectContext.ProjectDetails` has more then one phase item then it will throw exception.

But if there is no matching element then it will return 0

```
var numbers = new[] {1 ,2, 3};

numbers.Where(x => x == 6).SingleOrDefault(); // returns 0
```

because

```
default(int) == 0
```

Comment: In the OPs case it will return `null` since `ProjectDetail` is a reference type.

Answer (score -2):

It should work, just debuge and check either the int record exist in db or not, however try with

> .FirstOrDefault() insted of .SingleOrDefault() as it will give exceptional error if there is multiple result;

Comment: let me try this

Comment: .FirstOrDefault() will also return 0 if collection has no matching elements

Comment: Try `.Any` as suggested by two different people and there will be less code.